# Custom queryset/manager for default django User model

Tags: python, django

I am heavily using custom [querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.as_manager).

For all my models and it's working great. I have clean DRY code without any custom queries all over the place. I'd like to also add some custom query to my User object.

I am guessing, I should do something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
get_user_model().objects = MyCustomManager() #(or query.as_manager())
```

While creating MyCustomManager being derived from [BaseUserManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager).

Is that correct approach? If not, how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: I would not override the default manager, but add an additional one. If you don't want to swap the user model, you can just attach it (```setattr``` e.g.) on your ```AppConfig``` ```ready``` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/